# How to set a custom timeout to http.request in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have an http request that sometimes receives no response (timeout err0r). How should I handle this, perhaps reducing the original timeout and then repeating the request some number of times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` in the request.

Take a look at: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback